# Opening a directory chooser in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am writing a quick and dirty application that reads all the files from a given directory.  I'm currently using the OpenFileDialog to choose a directory and just culling off the file name that it provides.  It seems like there should be a way to just choose directories though, but in a quick browsing of MSDN I didn't find it.

If you have a way in winforms or more preferably in WPF I'm all ears.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll want to use a [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

```
using FORMS = System.Windows.Forms;

var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
FORMS.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == FORMS.DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Result: " + dialog.SelectedPath);
}
```